# Convert jmockit to mockito

Tags: java, mockito, java-17, jmockit

I have a test class where I am using `jmockit` with the sample code

```
 public class Test {
    
      @Before
      public void init() {
        mockClient(true, true);
      }
    
      private void mockClient(boolean arg1, boolean arg2) {
        new MockUp<Client>() {
          @Mock
          public ClientTO clentDetail(Map<String, String> Data) {
            ClientTO clientTO;
            ..
            do {
              something
                  .
            }.
    
            return clientTO;
          }
        };
      }
    }
```

the actual clentDetail implementation different from the above code

```
public class Client(){

    public ClientTO clentDetail(Map<String, String> Data) {
        ClientTO clientTO;
        ..
        do something
        ..

        return clientTO;
      }
}
```

i want to convert this jmockit to mockito as part of java17 upgrade, how can we do it?

can someone please help me in this.

Thanks.

Comment: What did your old mock do? I can't really make that out from your posted code. What are `arg1` and `arg2`? `Mockito.mock` creates a new mock instance.

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting, in this code i want different implementation to be called in the test case (where arg1 and arg2 will be used) and not the actual method,

Comment: It's still unclear. Can you [edit] your question to include a full [mre] – one that's actually compileable and working?